# How do I use CAM::PDF::Annot (perl module) without erroring?

Tags: perl, pdf, hash, annotations

I have been trying to use CAM:PDF::Annot for it's most basic purpose, aggregating the annotations of two pdf's, but have not had any success.

I have been trying to emulate what is in the package's synopsis on CPAN, but keep coming up with an error.

The code in the CPAN synopsis (as a completed script), or any advice would be helpful.

CPAN page: [http://metacpan.org/pod/CAM::PDF::Annot](http://metacpan.org/pod/CAM%3a%3aPDF%3a%3aAnnot)

So far I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict
use CAM::PDF;
use CAM::PDF::Annot;

sub main()
{
   my $pdf = CAM::PDF::Annot->new( 'testAnnotPDF.pdf' );
   my $otherDoc = CAM::PDF::Annot->new( 'testAnnotPDF2.pdf' );
   my $page = 1;
   my %refs;
   my $hrefs = \%refs;
   for my $annotRef  (@{$pdf->getAnnotations($page)}){
       $otherDoc->appendAnnotation( $page, $pdf, $annotRef, $hrefs );
   }
   $otherDoc->output('pdf_merged.pdf');
}
exit main;
```

Comment: What code have you written that throws this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the `getAnnotations()` method appears to return an array reference, whereas the `appendAnnotation()` method takes an annotation object and not an array reference. Try doing what the documetation says:

```
for my $annotRef ( @{$pdf->getAnnotations( $page )} ) {
  $otherDoc->appendAnnotation( $page, $pdf, $annotRef, \%refs );
}
```

You're not looping over all of the annotation references that you get back from `getAnnotations()`, you're just trying to stick the full array reference in there, and that's not going to work.